# Windows 8.1 and Android Lollipop USB Tethering strange behavior

Tags: windows-8.1, android, cpu-usage, windows-services, tethering

I have a problem under Windows 8.1 when I try to use internet through an Android USB Tethering...
I have a nexus 5 and when I enabled the USB Tethering, it works fine (I can navigate and use internet), but windows has some strange behavior, it became very slow...

The event viewer show a lot of errors: (look the screenshots below)

[image]

[image]

Here's the XML of one warning.

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-DeviceSetupManager" Guid="{FCBB06BB-6A2A-46E3-ABAA-246CB4E508B2}" /> 
  <EventID>201</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>3</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-03-01T20:18:08.967578100Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>27628</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="524" ThreadID="5304" /> 
  <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-DeviceSetupManager/Admin</Channel> 
  <Computer>Marco-PC</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
  <EventData /> 
  </Event>
```

The task manager and the resource monitor too:

Taskmanager got really slow and the refresh rate is about 1 step every 30/40seconds...

[image]

The resource monitor refresh looks fine, but there is a 109% of CPU and an high disk usage...

[image]

I tried usb debugging, changing the usb port, restart the computer, and other solutions...

Here's my hardware specs:
Phone: Android Nexus 5 Lollipop 5.0.1 stock (Build: LRX22C)

Computer:
CPU: Intel i5 4670K + Arctic Freezer i30 
RAM: Corsair 8GB /1600Mhz Vengeance LP Blue 
VGA: nVidia Gigabyte GTX 770 2GB 
MOBO: Gigabyte GA-Z87X-UD3H 
HDD 1: Samsung 840PRO 256GB 
HDD 2: WD Caviar Blue 1TB
ALI: Antec HCG-M620W HC-GAMER

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same problem with an older android device (desire z). It's very strange the way windows begin to behave. I feel like this started for me after I installed the past 3 months worth of windows updates.

Comment: Tried a second android device. Same problem. If you google something like "android tether windows 8.1 task manager" you see quite a few other people are having the same problem. http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/help/usb-tethering-t2553034 Gigabyte motherboards seem to be highly represented http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/bsod-after-attempting-to-tether-my-phone/f78368fb-7391-41c0-82cc-f58fcf149326

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem for years. 
This issue crosses multiple versions of Windows.
But finally I found the solution: Override installation of the RNDIS6 driver
(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2923775 - This is a similar related issue that explains our problem)

Follow the steps in the picture, Start in the Device Manager, then select your tethering device. With right-click follow the update driver option. Select the second options: "Find driver in my PC" (DO NOT let it automatically select).
When you hit the "Use disk..." option as in the image, locate the folder `C:\Windows\INF`. Turn off the "Show compatible hardware only" option and the full driver list will appear. Find Microsoft and then select the NDIS6 driver.

[image: How to solve]

I hope be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. [ClockworkMod Tether](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.tether&hl=en) works well for me.